# Windows 7 Enterprise Edition logon - are files installed from a local server?

Tags: windows-7, performance, login

when my daughter logs on to a windows 7 enterprise edition laptop at school it takes a long time.  Are there transfers of files from a local server to the laptop involved in this, or is the delay most likely due to other things.  (I seem to (mis?)recall from a previous life when I worked in an environment like this there were large files transferred from a local server to the desktop I logged on to first time I logged on to the machine.)  I don't have access to technical info about the setup at my daughter's school, sorry.  Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be going on.

First of all, does this happen when she is at school as well, or only when she is at home?  If it happens only at home, the laptop is likely trying to contact a server at the school for whatever reason and is waiting for a timeout on the response.  It could be a logon script or possibly it's just waiting for a domain controller that isn't reachable because she is not on the school's WiFi.

The solution for that is to turn off the wireless switch.  That will cause it to immediately fail and proceed logging on with cached credentials.  Then turn the switch back on and you're good to go.

Also, does the school use roaming profiles for the students?  If that's the case, then it's probably trying to sync her profile with the server copy.  That is a notorious issue with roaming profiles and possibly what you're recalling from that previous life.  You'd probably want to work with the school's IT department on that one.

Comment: Thanks Wes Sayeed, only happens at school (she's not allowed to take it home).  I may or may not be able to talk to the school's IT (I think its just a teacher who takes it on and they're kind of busy).  Would turning off the WiFi to log in (then turning it back on)  also work at school?  If the syncing is on, and a lot of students are logging in, might that generate a lot of network traffic (it sometimes gets pretty congested)?

Comment: The switch trick would work at school as well, but if they are using roaming profiles that would prevent the profile from ever syncing with the server. Roaming profiles only sync at logon/logoff. They cause problems for organizations that use them because if you copied large files to your desktop for example, it would take forever to log on/off the computer. Most places that use roaming profiles also use folder redirection and offline caching, which mitigates that problem. That can definitely cause slowness issues if those things go awry. But it's still an IT issue if it's happening at school.

Comment: The support headaches involved are why most organizations don't use roaming profiles.  So the school probably doesn't either.  If they don't, then it's probably getting hung up on a logon script. Still an IT problem though!  I am assuming the computer is heavily locked-down.  That limits your ability to do much of anything about it on your own.